# How to check passport personal token is expired or revoke?

Tags: php, laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

I'm using Laravel as a backend API for my react app. I want to return an error message if the token is either expired or revoked access. However, on my Authenticate middleware, I only able to catch AuthenticationException. This exception only returns the message "Unauthenticated." Below is my current code inside Authenticate middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards) {
    try {
        $this->authenticate($request, $guards);
    } catch (AuthenticationException $e) {
        $data['token'] = false;

        return ResponseServices::error(__('Auth.token_expired', []))
            ->data($data)
            ->toJson();
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

I tried to catch the exception using OAuthServerException and Throwable but not able to catch it. Only possible to catch AuthenticationException.

However, if I dd Throwable inside handler class on reportable function, I able to get this information [image]

Is it possible to get the hint message inside my middleware?

Comment: On react you'll get http codes  and they are clear enough. You don't need message from backend .

Comment: @MHIdea it will only return 401 http code. I need to differentiate the error is due to token expired or due to token is revoked access.